# Parameters with spacebars parsed incorrectly for a powershell script run from a batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, script, powershell, batch-file

I have a batch file that runs a powershell script and I need to pass two parameters to the script. In my batch it looks like this:

```
powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned -File "my script.ps1" "my path1\" "my path2\somefile.txt"
```

The way it is now, the parameters for my powershell script get completely messed up and I get:

- my path1" my
- path2\somefile.txt

I tried encapsulating my params with `'` and `` ` `` characters and I nearly got what I want, but the second quote character remains in the powershell script. What I get is this:

```
powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned -File "my script.ps1" "'my path1\'" "'my path2\somefile.txt'"
```

- 'my path1\'
- 'my path2\somefile.txt'

And what I want is this

- my path1\
- my path2\somefile.txt

I know I can strip the redundant quotes in the powershell script, but is there a better way to do this? In other words, **how can I pass those parameters to the powershell in a way that keeps them sane?**

Test powershell script:

```
echo $args[0]
echo $args[1]
```

Comment: I just noticed that the first parameter ends with a \ character which appears to work as an escape character. Now I need to figure out how to work around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. The problem was the trailing slash in the first parameter. This slash was escaping my quote and because of that it wasn't working as a quote (yet powershell still cut the string at some later space for whatever reason).

My batch file was autogenerated but I managed to fix it by adding another slash at the end of the first parameter (which was expected to end with a slash).

```
powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned -File "my script.ps1" "my path1\\" "my path2\somefile.txt"
```

This problem is probably not specific to batch files and is more than likely also affecting running powershell scripts from command line.